replace strings in an xml document using a 1:1 replacement file
For a Linux OS to be distributed I have an Openbox menu.xml file that contains about 30 words that would need to be translated for that menu to be localized. I assembled a .csv document with two columns: the English originals in the first (a couple of which include a space), translations in the second. I will be repeating this for something like 12 languages.
Here is a sample menu entry in which "File manager" is the target for translation:
<item label="File manager">
    <action name="Execute"><execute>thunar</execute></action>
  </item>

I need a way to search the menu.xml document string-by-string, replacing all occurrences of a given string with a translation. BTW: functional terms such as execute, action, item etc. do not appear in the csv list.
From an earlier project I have a script in R from my son that works with a flat file (Fluxbox menu) but does not make the substitutions in this case so I hope to find a Bash solution with which I am familiar. Thanks for any help.

What is the expected output and what you have tried? This is a task for xidel/xmlstarlet/xmllint

Are you replacing only //item/@label values or some other parts of the XML as well?

Provide a MRE example (ie input and expected output). In the simplest form you may even be able to just use sed to replace the values. The canonical solution would of course be XSLT

No, sed is not XML aware. I gave the accurate tools.

@GillesQuénot That's why I said "in the simplest case"

Easy job in python, if this is a option for you?

@Hermann12: python is fine

@choroba the two items involved are "item label" and "label" (for submenus)

@GillesQuénot the expected output is "menu.xml_de" or another language code, where all the entries on the csv had been substituted with the translations

Because you said, python could be a solution:
Updated, for namespace!
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

root = ET.parse("menu.xml").getroot()
ns = {'': 'http://openbox.org/', 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
ET.register_namespace('', "http://openbox.org/")

# csv English, French
with open("translate.csv", "r") as f:
    csvFile =csv.reader(f)
    for lines in csvFile:
        print(lines[0], lines[1])

        for item in root.findall('.//{*}menu', ns):
            for m in item.iter():
                if m.tag == "{http://openbox.org/}item":
                    if m.get('label') == lines[0]:
                        m.set("label",lines[1].lstrip())

# Pretty Print and write to file
print()
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.indent(tree, space="  ")
tree.write("menu_fr.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")

ET.dump(root)

Output:
File manager  Gestionnaire de fichiers
File  fichier

<openbox_menu xmlns="http://openbox.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://openbox.org/ file:///usr/share/openbox/menu.xsd">
  <menu id=" ID " label=" TITEL " icon=" SYMBOL ">
    <item label="Gestionnaire de fichiers" icon=" SYMBOL "> AKTIONEN 
  </item>
    <separator label="Überschrift" />
    <menu id=" ID " />
    <separator />
    <menu id=" ID " label=" TITEL " icon=" SYMBOL ">
      <item label="fichier" icon="SYMBOL"> AKTIONEN 
    </item>
    </menu>
    <separator />
    <item label="LABEL" icon="SYMBOL"> AKTIONEN 
  </item>
  </menu>
</openbox_menu>


Thanks for the python, I'll give it a workout today.

I ran a test using a German csv, changing only the name of the output file to "menu_de.xml". The parsing of the csv looks correct, but no actual substitution occurred and an incomprehensible "ns0" appears throughout.

Here is a sample of the end of the csv and the beginning of the output:`Shutdown Herunterfahren
Systray Systray
Terminal Terminal
Theme Thema
Wallpaper Hintergrundbild
<ns0:openbox_menu xmlns:ns0="http://openbox.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://openbox.org/                                   file:///usr/share/openbox/menu.xsd">
<ns0:menu id="root-menu" label="Openbox 3">
<ns0:item label="All apps">
<ns0:action name="Execute">
ns0:executejgmenu_run</ns0:execute>
</ns0:action>
</ns0:item>`

I see in a web search on "python3 ns0" that this is a known issue, but unsure how to change the code.

@Jerry Bond Please add a dummy xml with the root element in you question. It seems your xml contain namespaces. In this case you have to adapt the python script. I have changed the code, but don‘t know if this map your xml.

That revision works, excellent. Thanks very much!

I'm not sure what you want me to supply, but here is the top of the menu: `
<openbox_menu xmlns="http://openbox.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://openbox.org/                                   file:///usr/share/openbox/menu.xsd">



jgmenu_run

`
In further testing, I noticed that the submenu labels were not being translated. After looking closely at the code, I found that the following addition in the middle section would solve that.       for menu in root.findall('.//{*}menu', ns):             for m in menu.iter():                 if m.tag == "{http://openbox.org/}menu":                     if m.get('label') == lines[0]:                         m.set("label",lines[1].lstrip())

This is a good use case for a template engine, like the Template::Toolkit's tpage command:
you need to copy the XML and edit it to add variables like I do here with variable v:
<root>
<item label="File manager">
    <action name="[% v %]<execute>thunar</execute></action>
  </item>
</root>

then, tun the tpage command line for each line in your CSV:
tpage --define v=EDITED  file
<root>
<item label="File manager">
    <action name="EDITED<execute>thunar</execute></action>
  </item>
</root>

Or with xmlstarlet:
xmlstarlet ed -u '//action[@name="Execute"]/@name' -v "EDITED" file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item label="File manager">
    <action name="EDITED">
      <execute>thunar</execute>
    </action>
  </item>
</root>


Check libtemplate-perl Debian's package or equivalent for your distro.
